# SQLite c# parameters

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to execute an `SQLiteCommand` containing 3 inserts to 3 separate tables. In all 3 tables the primary key is called `offset`. In the 3rd statement, I want to insert two rows.

There are a total of 11 parameters to the command

Here is the code I used to initialize the command earlier (I want to reuse the command, but this particular problem occurs even on the first use of this statement):

```
_insertBlockInNewPage = new SQLiteCommand("insert into page(offset) values (?); insert into block(offset, length, originaloffset, page) values (?, ?, ?, ?); insert into chunk(offset, length, page, free) values (?, ?, ?, 0), (?, ?, ?, 1)", _db);
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(DbType.Int64));
_insertBlockInNewPage.Prepare();
```

And here is the method that will use this command:

```
public void InsertBlockInNewPage(long offset, long length, long originalOffset, long pageLength)
{
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[0].Value = offset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[1].Value = offset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[2].Value = length;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[3].Value = originalOffset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[4].Value = offset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[5].Value = offset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[6].Value = length;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[7].Value = offset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[8].Value = offset + length;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[9].Value = pageLength - length;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.Parameters[10].Value = offset;
    _insertBlockInNewPage.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

What is important here that parameter 5 has the value 0 and parameter 8 has the value 131072 (i.e. not the same). When I execute this command it throws an Exception telling me that the primary key must be unique.

What's weird is that if I only insert one row in the chunk table it works. What's weirder is if I execute the insert of the chunk table in a separate `SQLiteCommand`, but still inserting 2 rows simultaneously it works too. So i'm guessing I must have done something wrong with the parameters. But I really cannot see anything wrong with this code. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, parameter indexes are counted from the start of the SQL statement.

This implies that it is not possible to use unnamed parameters together with multiple SQL commands in one `SQLCommand`.

You could try to use numbered parameters:

```sql
insert into page(offset) values (?1);
insert into block(offset, length, originaloffset, page) values (?2, ?3, ?4, ?5);
...
```